# Bash Script to find the words in one file but not another. Given two files

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash

I need a bash script to list all the words in a file, but not in another file. I have the filepaths.

Comment: What have you tried so far? "Give me teh codez plz" isn't popular around here.

Comment: i dont think so. i can't find a nyc way to do it.

Comment: provide sample input files and expected output

Comment: A New York City way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You want `comm`

Presuming your files are sorted

```
comm -2 -3 file1 file2
```

If the files are not sorted, sort them first

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Note that this lists lines, not words. To get words you'd have to split your files into lines first.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v -f file2 file1
```

should do the trick if there are no special characters in the words in the second file and if they are one-per-line.

Comment: it ain't one per line. It's like a para.

Comment: Then make it one per line. tr ' ' '\n' is your friend :-). You can also do that in a pipe when using "-f -".